# JQuery Mobile Page Aliases

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, alias, mustache

Is it possible to add aliases to a page in JQuery Mobile so that a hash change to either name will cause the page to be shown?

**Background**
Hello everyone, I am making an MVC style JQuery Mobile app where each page has its own JavaScript controller. Then on JQMs `PageBeforeShow` event the relevant controller renders the page using a Mustache template before it is shown.

In my app I have three JQM page containers in the document body that look like this:

```
<div data-role='page' id='profile'></div>
<div data-role='page' id='editprofile'></div>
<div data-role='page' id='register'></div>
```

These pages all use the same controller and mustache template because they have very similar content but this obviously creates a lot of duplicate content after you visit each page.

What I would prefer is a single JQM page that is loaded when the hash changes to either `#profile`, `#editprofile` or `#register`.

Does anyone know if JQuery Mobile supports this or if there is a viable workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use changePage to transition to the page specified by the page id.

```
$.mobile.changePage ('#profile');
$.mobile.changePage ('#editprofile');
$.mobile.changePage ('#register');
```